# WPF singelton intance gives null exception, before singelton value is set

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have created a Singelton

```
static readonly License_plateRequests _instance = new License_plateRequests();

private License_plateRequests()
{
}

public static License_plateRequests instance
{
    get { return _instance; }
}

public License_plate license_plateFirst { get; set; }
```

I run a clickevent in a page, to run some code where i set the singelton value. Its my first application in WPF so, i dont know if the patteren is right.

```
private async void enterButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ImageStatus.Source.ToString() == "pack://application:,,,/ParkeringsApp;component/Countries/Denmark-icon.png")
    {
        nationality = "DK";
    }
    if (ImageStatus.Source.ToString() == "pack://application:,,,/ParkeringsApp;component/Countries/Germany-icon.png")
    {
        nationality = "GER";
    }
    if (ImageStatus.Source.ToString() == "pack://application:,,,/ParkeringsApp;component/Countries/Norway-icon.png")
    {
        nationality = "NOR";
    }
    if (ImageStatus.Source.ToString() == "pack://application:,,,/ParkeringsApp;component/Countries/Sweden-icon.png")
    {
        nationality = "SWE";
    }
    if (ImageStatus.Source.ToString() == "pack://application:,,,/ParkeringsApp;component/Countries/United-Kingdom-flat-icon.png")
    {
        nationality = "GB";
    }

    var data = await loginRequest.LoginAsync();
    var token = await loginRequest.ParkingToken(data.jwt);
    var licenseplate = await licensePlate.LicensePlate(token, nationality, numberplateInput.Content.ToString());
    var parkings = await licensePlate.getParkingById(token, licenseplate.id);
    try
    {
        foreach (var parking in parkings)
        {
            if (parking == null)
            {
                parkingRequests.ParkCar(token, "aca0cd99-e392-4069-847f-8953ca86d7e6", licenseplate.id);
                NavigationService.Navigate(new RegistredPage());
            }
            else if (parking.time_end == 0)
            {
                NavigationService.Navigate(paymentPage, licenseplate);
                licensePlate.license_plateFirst.country.alpha2 = nationality;
            }
            else
            {
                parkingRequests.ParkCar(token, "aca0cd99-e392-4069-847f-8953ca86d7e6", licenseplate.id);
                NavigationService.Navigate(new RegistredPage());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Then i navigate by NavigationService to the next page PaymentPage. 
I get a nullpointer Exception in PaymentPage.

```
public partial class PaymentPage : Page
{
    License_plateRequests licensePlate = License_plateRequests.instance;

    public PaymentPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(licensePlate.license_plateFirst.country.alpha2);
    }
}
```

I get the null pointer when i try to run the application. I havent set the value yet, so offcourse

```
licensePlate.license_plateFirst.country.alpha2
```

gives me null. But i havent loaded that page yet, and i havent set the value. 
How can i handle this, so i can get the value when the page is first loaded?

Comment: A bit dirty maybe, but in the constructor of `PaymentPage` check for null: `if(licensePlate.license_plateFirst.country.alpha2 != null)`?

Comment: The problem is that when the project compile i get the null pointer. So even if i check for null i can't compile my projekt.

Comment: I get this error Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in ParkeringsApp.exe
ParkeringsApp.HttpRequests.License_plateRequests.license_plateFirst.**get** returned null                                                                                                           This is when i try to run the projekt

Comment: I don´t get why wpf calls the constructor, when compiling ?

Comment: My guess is that somewhere in your code you are trying to access the properties of the object `License_plateRequests` but that doesn't work, because the object itself is `null` resp. not initialized. How far did you get with debugging your code from start to end?

Comment: I'm not that deep in the magic behind WPF, I'm afraid.

Comment: You certainly don't get a NullReferenceException during compilation. It's a runtime exception. Where are you initializing license_plateFirst? You need to do this before you access any of its properties.

Comment: Im initializing  an intance of licensePlate in CarRegisterPage.xaml.cs like this:       License_plateRequests licensePlate = License_plateRequests.instance; and set licensePlate.license_plateFirst.country.alpha2 = nationality;.As you can see in secound code example

Comment: This is more of a debugging issue and not WPF.  I would also suggest you read this article on singletons (especially the part on BeforeFieldInit) http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx